# Send transcribed, spoken text from smart speakers/displays to server after Conversational Action shutdown?

Tags: actions-on-google

If I need to explain how insanely important and useful this functionality is, please let me know.  However, I suspect this is obvious to everyone except Google.

Please, please tell me there is another way to accomplish this.

I need to do all speech parsing, processing, and responses on my own.  And from a smart speaker/display.  Conversational Actions allowed for this.  As far as I have been able to tell, there is no alternative way to accomplish this.  I'm shocked and severely disappointed.  You're literally crippling your smart speakers and displays.  I have one in every room right now and will be selling them after the shutdown unless something changes.  I sure hope you reverse course on this.

Answer (score 0):

We noted your ask here and will continue to monitor for other similar requests involving the [Conversational Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset#:%7E:text=On%20June%2013%2C%202023%2C%20the,available%20to%20users%20or%20developers.) in our support channels. We do collect these requests, share with the teams involved in the planning process, and try to get them in our feature development timeline.

Unfortunately there are no features readily available to replace the capability you mentioned above, but our teams are constantly working towards providing a better Google Smart Home Ecosystem. When we have any updates on these features, we will update our public documentation.